Pipenv install error, failed building wheel for hdbscan
When trying to install the specific library hdbscan which is needed for another library, the installation fails.
This happens in virtual environment that's managed by pipenv, running python 3.12 in VSC. I've been reluctant on rolling back the version because some other packages require 3.12, I'd run into more problems if I go for an older version, so I'm hoping for a solution.
The error log output:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting cython==0.29.37 (from -r c:\users\kuype\appdata\local\temp\pipenv-vauzfe18-requirements\pipenv-p_p6a5vy-hashed-reqs.txt (line 1))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached Cython-0.29.37-py2.py3-none-any.whl (989 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting hdbscan==0.8.33 (from -r c:\users\kuype\appdata\local\temp\pipenv-vauzfe18-requirements\pipenv-p_p6a5vy-hashed-reqs.txt (line 2))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached hdbscan-0.8.33.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Installing build dependencies: started
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Building wheels for collected packages: hdbscan
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Building wheel for hdbscan (pyproject.toml): started
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Building wheel for hdbscan (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Failed to build hdbscan
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: error: subprocess-exited-with-error
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   × Building wheel for hdbscan (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   │ exit code: 1
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ╰─> [42 lines of output]
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running bdist_wheel
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running build
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running build_py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\hdbscan
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying hdbscan\flat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\hdbscan
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying hdbscan\hdbscan_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\hdbscan
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying hdbscan\plots.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\hdbscan
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying hdbscan\prediction.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\hdbscan
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying hdbscan\robust_single_linkage_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\hdbscan
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying hdbscan\validity.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\hdbscan
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying hdbscan\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\hdbscan
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\hdbscan\tests
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying hdbscan\tests\test_flat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\hdbscan\tests
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying hdbscan\tests\test_hdbscan.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\hdbscan\tests
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying hdbscan\tests\test_prediction_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\hdbscan\tests
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying hdbscan\tests\test_rsl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\hdbscan\tests
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying hdbscan\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\hdbscan\tests
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running build_ext
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_tree.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_tree.c
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       C:\Users\Kuype\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u93dswof\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Kuype\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qyt1c1de\hdbscan_e4c88ec6cf3346c380d127c12bcf6096\hdbscan\_hdbscan_tree.pyx
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_linkage.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_linkage.c
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       C:\Users\Kuype\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u93dswof\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Kuype\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qyt1c1de\hdbscan_e4c88ec6cf3346c380d127c12bcf6096\hdbscan\_hdbscan_linkage.pyx
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_boruvka.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_boruvka.c
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       C:\Users\Kuype\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u93dswof\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Kuype\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qyt1c1de\hdbscan_e4c88ec6cf3346c380d127c12bcf6096\hdbscan\_hdbscan_boruvka.pyx
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_reachability.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_reachability.c
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       C:\Users\Kuype\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u93dswof\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Kuype\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qyt1c1de\hdbscan_e4c88ec6cf3346c380d127c12bcf6096\hdbscan\_hdbscan_reachability.pyx
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       cythoning hdbscan/_prediction_utils.pyx to hdbscan\_prediction_utils.c
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       C:\Users\Kuype\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u93dswof\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Kuype\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qyt1c1de\hdbscan_e4c88ec6cf3346c380d127c12bcf6096\hdbscan\_prediction_utils.pyx
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       cythoning hdbscan/dist_metrics.pyx to hdbscan\dist_metrics.c
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       C:\Users\Kuype\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u93dswof\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Kuype\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qyt1c1de\hdbscan_e4c88ec6cf3346c380d127c12bcf6096\hdbscan\dist_metrics.pxd
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       building 'hdbscan._hdbscan_tree' extension
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       [end of output]
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ERROR: Failed building wheel for hdbscan
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ERROR: Could not build wheels for hdbscan, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
ERROR: Couldn't install package: {}
 Package installation failed...

Things I've tried:

pipenv clean
reinstalled every package
"Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools" installed it on pc, restarted, but figured this wouldn't apply to a venv
pipenv install setuptools
pipenv install wheel
don't know how to use conda with pipenv (conda install -c conda-forge hdbscan)
when using conda install -c conda-forge hdbscan it is already installed
when using pipenv run conda install -c conda-forge hdbscan it is already installed but not added to pipfile.lock


"install c++ on pc" .. What did you actually install ? Error explicitly says it can't find MSVC and thats why the build fails. Instructions could be read from https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers. If you did that, you might need to run dev prompt described here; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-enable-a-64-bit-visual-cpp-toolset-on-the-command-line

Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools"
Followed the instructions of this line, then did a pipenv install setuptools, will try the dev prompt.

ran the pipenv install, in the dev prompt, same result, as I expected because it is a virtual environment.

Answering my own question after consulting multiple sources, seemed that the solution is much simpler I thought.
The required build packages for CPython dependencies, setuptools and wheel were located in [packages] in .\Pipfile, seems to be a result of running pipenv install wheel setuptools.
moving
[packages]
{urpackages} = "version"
hdbscan = "*"
wheel = "*"
setuptools = "*"

to
[packages]
hdbscan = "*"

[dev-packages]
wheel = "*"
setuptools = "*"

fixed the pipenv install hdbscan and eventually the pipenv install BERTopic steps.
